# Reset CSS styles after append with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am populating a DIV with content returned from a callback that has multiple HTML items in it and each have their own classes associated. After I call .append however the content isn't coming in with the proper associated styles.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "blah.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: myData,
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('appId');
            $('<li><h5 class="thing">' + id + '</h5>').appendTo('#results');
        });
    }
});
```

So it grabs the ID and sets the ID in there on an H5 with the class "thing", it then appends to the DIV results. That works fine, but the problem is when this happens the class named "thing" never gets applied. Its definitely there, but not getting rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: you are trying to get CSS styles with AJAX request?

Comment: sounds like your css rules aren't specific enough for the class. Use browser console to inspect rule rank for the elements, adjust rule specificity accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing to do with it. It just won't add the class attribute to begin with.

Comment: @bvukelic class is in the html string, not possible for it to dissapear without code removing the class

Comment: @charlietfl: Hm, you are right. I'm pretty sure I had this problem today with some code, but could be something else.

Comment: @jeremykrall Can you post the CSS rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#results').append('<li><h5 class="thing">' + id + '</h5>');
```

So, for many reasons, including performance reasons, and autoclosing of `<ul>`, etc, I suggest you first build your whole subtree as string.

```
var s = '<ul>';
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('appId');
    s += '<li><h5 class="thing">' + id + '</h5></li>';
});
$('#results').append(s + '</ul>');
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I am seeing one issue. When I try doing two of these (its a list) it auto closes the LI from the first one??

Comment: @jeremykrall How do you mean "auto closes"? What happens to LI?

Comment: this shouldn't do anything different than using `appendTo` as OP is doing

Comment: It is actually working the same way as my original code. What I am saying is when do $('#results').append('<ul>'); for example it actually returns <ul></ul>. Wondering why.

Comment: @charlietfl: Yes. I know. I had a weird issue today with some of my code which turned out to be completely unrelated to `appendTo` so I guess that kinda blurred my thoughts.

Comment: last statment is completely false... see `appendTo` docs  http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/   `selector` is perfectly valid argument. How would OP be getting the html insterted if it wasn't valid?

Comment: You guys see my question on how append (and appendTo) auto closes the tag? Any way around?

Answer (score 0):

use the tag "ul" if u want to use a list of "li"
so:

```
$('#results').append('<ul></ul>');
```

and then you have to write a code like this:

```
    var results = "";
    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('appId');
         results+= '<li><h5 class="thing">' + id + '</h5></li>';
     });
    $('#results ul').append(results);
```